# NoneType error with BeautifulSoup/Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I saw a number of similar posts, but none of them seemed to apply to my problem. Sorry if I just missed it.

I'm scraping a pretty large HTML table, and am formatting it so that it can be fed into a DB. One record has a blank column, which is resulting in a NoneType error when I try

```
print "|".join(record)
```

since the record looks like

```
(data, ... , None, data)
```

I tried to filter out the None's by applying the following before creating the record-tuple:

```
def null_converter(field):
    return field.string if field else "NULL"
```

But that didn't seem to work. Is there a better way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the None values:

```
record = ("data", None, "data")
[x for x in record if x is not None]
['data', 'data']
```

If you are sure you have no falsey values:

```
print filter(None,record)
('data', 'data')
```

Or:

```
  "|".join(map(str,records))
 In [6]: "|".join(map(str,d))
 Out[6]: 'data|None|data'
```

Some timings:

```
In [9]: d = ("data", None, "data") * 100

In [10]: %timeit [x if x is not None else "Null" for x in d ]
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.8 µs per loop

In [11]: %timeit "|".join(map(str,d))
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.9 µs per loop

In [12]: %timeit "|".join((str(field) for field in d))
10000 loops, best of 3: 66.3 µs per loop
```

`map` is  more efficient than looping over and casting but `list comp` is the fastest.

Comment: Ah right I just had to filter. I still need some sort of placeholder for ease of loading, so I used `record = ["NULL" if field is None else field for field in record]` 
Not the most efficient, but it works? Thank!

Comment: You're welcome.  I was not sure if you wanted to keep some null value placeholder or not but yes list comp is the easiest way .

Comment: I actually really don't understand why the null_checking function wasn't working though. The field was parsed, sent through the null checker, and stored as record. Now, I'm parsing the field, storing as record, and then null checking the entire record (instead of when I first parse), which is less efficient.

Comment: I was looking at that, if you want to post your code to pastebin I am sure I can see why it did not work, you do have the overhead of calling another function and checking each element so it would actually be interesting to see what performance difference there would be.

Comment: Here is one version of the code (URL itself is private, but it's just a large HTML table) http://pastie.org/private/nnff5mshedzujftyrmlfzg. 

I originally did not have an extra function, and was just doing the null check in the parse function, but it looked cluttered.Thanks!

Comment: one quick note, I would upgrade to bs4 if I were you.

Comment: Also use requests to retrieve the html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print "|".join((str(field) for field in record))
```

If that doesnt work, is it possible `record` itself is None (rather than a list/tuple)?